# Can we call a potential barrier in a program

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, synchronization

I want my threads to stop at a barrier point, but I want to only stop if a barrier is required. For example after a certain timer interval, I want all of threads to form a barrier. Is there a method to put a potential barrier point? For example at start of each function. I want something like this.

```
void some_function()
{
 potentially_barrier_wait;
 ......
}
```

So I want `potentially_barrier_wait` to only call a barrier if its required, otherwise `potentially_barrier_wait` do nothing. Can this thing be implemented satisfactorily? Will this also work in programs which already have barriers in them, or will it race with them.

Comment: Just wrap the barrier in an if-statement with whatever your condition is?

Comment: Mystical - That is my question, Can this be done without introducing race conditions, especially in a program that already has barriers.

Comment: Oh ic, you're afraid of a race condition in say - the if-condition.

Comment: depends on your condition. If your condition requires some non-atomic resource, you'll have to wrap the whole thing in a mutex. - so inside your if statement, write a small inline that closes and opens a mutex before checking the condition.

Comment: how are you implementing a barrier wait?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by barrier... if you are referring to simple synchronization, you can do it like this:

On Windows, create an event CreateEvent( 0, false, 0, 0 ).  In your thread, do a WaitForSingleObject on that.  In your "controlling" thread, SetEvent it to let it pass your barrier.  You can play with it to have it pre-set, and auto-release, etc.

On Linux, similar but you can use a pthread_cond_timedwait as your barrier, and signal it with pthread_cond_signal.

Comment: The OP is asking about rendezvous barriers, as seen in `pthread_barrier_*()`

Comment: Although the implementation of a barrier using a conditional variable will be complex for small programs it is possible; Mark is on the right path with his answer. If you look at [the source for pthread_barrier_wait](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_barrier_wait.c;h=89936a08c7e9fbb51d4eeb24b7f1619a059e0b39;hb=HEAD) it is simply a conditional variable across all threads.